# Can anyone explain what are this numbers `echo -ne "\033]0;Title\007"`

Tags: terminal, echo, title-bar

I'm using them for setting the terminal title or terminal tab title but want to know what the numbers refer to.
Could anyone please give me a hint on where I can find that info?

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/831971/what-type-of-sequences-are-escape-sequences-starting-with-033

Comment: Thanks for the link, however, it's not exactly what I was asking. The correct answer is here https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h3-Operating-System-Commands